Unity 2D Grappling Hook
I was trying to change a youtube tutorail (https://youtu.be/dnNCVcVS6uw?si=U6W97gX-sOr53uW7) abut grappling hook for controller but the code doesn't work at all. Instead of swinging the character move to a random point very fast. If someone can help me that would be great. Thanks
Here is the code and photos from inspector
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrapplingRope : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("General Refernces:")]
    public GrapplingHook grapplingGun;
    public LineRenderer m_lineRenderer;

    [Header("General Settings:")]
    [SerializeField] private int percision = 40;
    [Range(0, 20)] [SerializeField] private float straightenLineSpeed = 5;

    [Header("Rope Animation Settings:")]
    public AnimationCurve ropeAnimationCurve;
    [Range(0.01f, 4)] [SerializeField] private float StartWaveSize = 2;
    float waveSize = 0;

    [Header("Rope Progression:")]
    public AnimationCurve ropeProgressionCurve;
    [SerializeField] [Range(1, 50)] private float ropeProgressionSpeed = 1;

    float moveTime = 0;

    [HideInInspector] public bool isGrappling = true;

    bool strightLine = true;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        moveTime = 0;
        m_lineRenderer.positionCount = percision;
        waveSize = StartWaveSize;
        strightLine = false;

        LinePointsToFirePoint();

        m_lineRenderer.enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        m_lineRenderer.enabled = false;
        isGrappling = false;
    }

    private void LinePointsToFirePoint()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < percision; i++)
        {
            m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, grapplingGun.firePoint.position);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        moveTime += Time.deltaTime;
        DrawRope();
    }

    void DrawRope()
    {
        if (!strightLine)
        {
            if (m_lineRenderer.GetPosition(percision - 1).x == grapplingGun.grapplePoint.x)
            {
                strightLine = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DrawRopeWaves();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isGrappling)
            {
                grapplingGun.Grapple();
                isGrappling = true;
            }
            if (waveSize > 0)
            {
                waveSize -= Time.deltaTime * straightenLineSpeed;
                DrawRopeWaves();
            }
            else
            {
                waveSize = 0;

                if (m_lineRenderer.positionCount != 2) { m_lineRenderer.positionCount = 2; }

                DrawRopeNoWaves();
            }
        }
    }

    void DrawRopeWaves()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < percision; i++)
        {
            float delta = (float)i / ((float)percision - 1f);
            Vector2 offset = Vector2.Perpendicular(grapplingGun.grappleDistanceVector).normalized * ropeAnimationCurve.Evaluate(delta) * waveSize;
            Vector2 targetPosition = Vector2.Lerp(grapplingGun.firePoint.position, grapplingGun.grapplePoint, delta) + offset;
            Vector2 currentPosition = Vector2.Lerp(grapplingGun.firePoint.position, targetPosition, ropeProgressionCurve.Evaluate(moveTime) * ropeProgressionSpeed);

            m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, currentPosition);
        }
    }

    void DrawRopeNoWaves()
    {
        m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, grapplingGun.firePoint.position);
        m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, grapplingGun.grapplePoint);
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class GrapplingHook : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Scripts Ref:")]
    public GrapplingRope grappleRope;

    [Header("Layers Settings:")]
    [SerializeField] private bool grappleToAll = false;
    [SerializeField] private int grappableLayerNumber = 9;

    [Header("Transform Ref:")]
    public Transform gunHolder;
    public Transform firePoint;

    [Header("Physics Ref:")]
    public SpringJoint2D m_springJoint2D;
    public Rigidbody2D m_rigidbody;

    [Header("Distance:")]
    [SerializeField] private bool hasMaxDistance = false;
    [SerializeField] private float maxDistnace = 20;

    Collider2D[] hookPoints;
    public GameObject nearestHookPoint;

    private enum LaunchType
    {
        Transform_Launch,
        Physics_Launch
    }

    [Header("Launching:")]
    [SerializeField] private bool launchToPoint = true;
    [SerializeField] private LaunchType launchType = LaunchType.Physics_Launch;
    [SerializeField] private float launchSpeed = 1;

    [Header("No Launch To Point")]
    [SerializeField] private bool autoConfigureDistance = false;
    [SerializeField] private float targetDistance = 3;
    [SerializeField] private float targetFrequncy = 1;

    [HideInInspector] public Vector2 grapplePoint;
    [HideInInspector] public Vector2 grappleDistanceVector;

    private void Start()
    {
        grappleRope.enabled = false;
        m_springJoint2D.enabled = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float nearestDistance = float.MaxValue;
        hookPoints = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(firePoint.position, maxDistnace, LayerMask.GetMask("GrapplePoint", "enemy"));

        foreach (Collider2D hookPoint in hookPoints)
        {
            float dist = Vector2.Distance(hookPoint.transform.position, transform.position);

            if (dist < nearestDistance)
            {
                nearestDistance = dist;
                nearestHookPoint = hookPoint.gameObject;
            }
        }

        if (nearestHookPoint != null && nearestHookPoint.CompareTag("swingPoint"))
        {
            launchToPoint = false;
        }
        else
        {
            launchToPoint = true;
        }
    }

    public void Hook(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.started)
        {
            if (hookPoints != null && nearestHookPoint != null)
            {
                SetGrapplePoint();
                Grapple(); // Grapple fonksiyonunu çağırmayı unutmayın
            }
        }
        else if (context.performed)
        {
            if (hookPoints != null && nearestHookPoint != null)
            {
                Vector2 hookPointPosition = nearestHookPoint.transform.position;

                if (launchToPoint && grappleRope.isGrappling)
                {
                    if (launchType == LaunchType.Transform_Launch)
                    {
                        Vector2 firePointDistnace = firePoint.position - gunHolder.localPosition;
                        Vector2 targetPos = grapplePoint - firePointDistnace;
                        gunHolder.position = Vector2.Lerp(gunHolder.position, targetPos, Time.deltaTime * launchSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (context.canceled)
        {
            grappleRope.enabled = false;
            m_springJoint2D.enabled = false;
            m_rigidbody.gravityScale = 1;
        }
    }


    void SetGrapplePoint()
    {
        if (nearestHookPoint == null) return;

        Vector2 distanceVector = nearestHookPoint.transform.position - firePoint.position;
        RaycastHit2D _hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePoint.position, distanceVector.normalized);

        if (_hit.collider != null) // _hit.collider ile hit kontrolü yapıyoruz
        {
            if (_hit.transform.gameObject.layer == grappableLayerNumber || grappleToAll)
            {
                if (Vector2.Distance(_hit.point, firePoint.position) <= maxDistnace || !hasMaxDistance)
                {
                    grapplePoint = _hit.point;
                    grappleDistanceVector = grapplePoint - (Vector2)firePoint.position;
                    grappleRope.enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Grapple()
    {
        m_springJoint2D.autoConfigureDistance = false;
        if (!launchToPoint && !autoConfigureDistance)
        {
            m_springJoint2D.distance = targetDistance;
            m_springJoint2D.frequency = targetFrequncy;
        }
        if (!launchToPoint)
        {
            if (autoConfigureDistance)
            {
                m_springJoint2D.autoConfigureDistance = true;
                m_springJoint2D.frequency = 0;
            }

            m_springJoint2D.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;
            m_springJoint2D.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (launchType)
            {
                case LaunchType.Physics_Launch:
                    m_springJoint2D.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;

                    Vector2 distanceVector = firePoint.position - gunHolder.position;

                    m_springJoint2D.distance = distanceVector.magnitude;
                    m_springJoint2D.frequency = launchSpeed;
                    m_springJoint2D.enabled = true;
                    break;
                case LaunchType.Transform_Launch:
                    m_rigidbody.gravityScale = 0;
                    m_rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (firePoint != null && hasMaxDistance)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(firePoint.position, maxDistnace);
        }
    }
}


